# excel data is not uploaded to mysql workbench using python

Tags: python, mysql-workbench

Data is not uploaded to mysql-workbench

I checked mysql-workbench

```py
import xlrd
import pymysql

book = xlrd.open_workbook("c:/Temp/exportimport201006.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("201006")

database = pymysql.connect(host = 'xxx', user = 'xxx', password = 'xxx', db = 'xxx')
cursor = database.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO exportimport (year, hscode, expwgt, expdlr, impwgt, impdlr, balpayments) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

for r in range(2, sheet.nrows):
    year = sheet.cell(r,0).value
    hscode = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    expwgt = sheet.cell(r,2).value
    expdlr = sheet.cell(r,3).value
    impwgt = sheet.cell(r,4).value
    impdlr = sheet.cell(r,5).value
    balpayments = sheet.cell(r,6).value

    values = (year,hscode,expwgt,expdlr,impwgt,impdlr,balpayments)
    cursor.execute(query, values)

database.close()
```

It doesn't finish nevertheless data is not large

Which part is wrong?

I'm python beginner

Comment: Now tell me in what sense this python code relates to MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the commit operation after `cursor.execute`.

Coding like this:

```py
database.commit()
```